# Filewriter creates a file that is read-only

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I use a filewriter to write an arraylist of objects to a file, as strings, in a kind- of CSV like format. Anyway I had problems getting it to work, but now I get a FileNotFound exception and it says the file created is read-only in the exception. The file is created, as I checked, but apparently cannot be written to. However I actually want to overwrite the contents anyway, but get this error.

```
        ///Like a CSV file. 
        try{
            FileWriter writer_file = new FileWriter("PeopleDetailsFile");

            String filestring = ""; ///initializes filestring, which is written to the file.
            for(PeopleDetails person : peopledetails_file){
                String person_detail_string = "";
                person_detail_string = person.name + "," + person.number;
                filestring = filestring + person_detail_string + ";";

            }
            writer_file.write(filestring);
            writer_file.close();
        }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());

        }finally{
            ///Hopefully won't get an error here.
            Intent switch_menu = new Intent(this, MenuList.class);
            startActivity(switch_menu);
        }
```

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions? Also make sure you haven't connected your device to your computer when working with files, because while you have access to the files from your computer you cannot access them from the apps.

Comment: what permissions do I need? Writing to internal data files for my app (hopefully :)) running on emulator

Comment: In one of your other questions, you say that the file (same code) is not created, what's going on?  BTW, have you consider reading the documentation for these methods?  You really should get into the habit of understanding classes before you try to use them.

Comment: aah...crap, I put the wrong code up, hence the different problem, but same code!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this method with `fileName` and the `List` as Argument.

```
public void fileWrite(String fileName,ArrayList<PeopleDetails> person){
        File           f ;
        FileWriter     fw = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            f  = new File(fileName);
            fw = new FileWriter(f.getAbsoluteFile());
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for(PeopleDetails i:person){
                bw.write(i.name+","+i.number+";");
                bw.newLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                if(bw!=null)
                    bw.close();
                if(fw!=null)
                    fw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the PrintWriter. I am providing you some brief guidelines below, but modifications will be required. Moreover, note that I am saving the name and the number in different lines, so when you read the details you should use the same approach.

```
 public void writeToFile(String fileName, ArrayList<PeopleDetails> peopledetails) {
        try {
            /*
             * Create a FileWriter object that handles the low-level details of
             * writing
             */
            FileWriter theFile = new FileWriter(fileName);

            /* Create a PrintWriter object to wrap around the FileWriter object */
            /* This allows the use of high-level methods like println */
            PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter(theFile);

            /* Print some lines to the file using the println method */
            for (int i = 0; i < peopledetails.size(); i++) {
                fileOut.println(peopledetails.get(i).getName());
                fileOut.println(peopledetails.get(i).getNumber());
            }
            /* Close the file so that it is no longer accessible to the program */
            fileOut.close();
        }

        /* Handle the exception thrown by the FileWriter methods */
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem writing to the file");
        }
    } /* End of method writeToFile */
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try deleting the file every time you wan't to rewrite it.
     try{

```
        File file = new File("PeopleDetailsFile");

        if(file.delete()){
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Alternatively: you could make the FileWriter to where it appends to the current document:

```
 FileWriter writer_file = new FileWriter("PeopleDetailsFile", true); //true means append = true;
```

Comment: a possible solution, but not ideal. thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the other constructor of FileWriter that takes append flag: FileWriter(File file, boolean append)

Comment: yep, but the point is to overwrite it, so that I can order it. If I append, it won't be ordered. I could order it inside the app of course... thanks

Comment: So delete the old one before writing. It is obvious. Why didn't you do it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to write to the 'root' folder. You should be following Android Context [openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) instead of `FileWriter` to write to the application's directory (instead of the root).

Per the documentation:

> Open a private file associated with this Context's application package
>   for writing. Creates the file if it doesn't already exist.